# SQL Query with same first column, contains two values in the second column

Tags: sql

**This is an example, I couldn't use original data as it could be confidential**

I am trying to get values with the same first column, and contain two items for the second column.

For example, I want to show all deliveries that contain both MEAT and MILK on the same delivery (1000000001 and 1000000003).

Here is what I have, I just don't know what condition to use to show items with the same first column, and contain the two items needed.

```
SELECT DELIVERYNO, PRODUCT
FROM DELIVERY 
WHERE ........
```

```
DELIVERYNO  PRODUCT     
----------  ---------   
1000000001  MEAT
1000000001  EGGS
1000000001  MILK
1000000002  CHEESE
1000000002  MEAT
1000000003  MEAT
1000000003  CEREAL
1000000003  MILK
```

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Sample data in lines #1 - 10; query you might need begins at line #11.

```
SQL> with test (deliveryno, product) as
  2    (select 1, 'meat'   from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'eggs'   from dual union all
  4     select 1, 'milk'   from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'cheese' from dual union all
  6     select 2, 'meat'   from dual union all
  7     select 3, 'meat'   from dual union all
  8     select 3, 'cereal' from dual union all
  9     select 3, 'milk'   from dual
 10    )
 11  select deliveryno
 12  from test
 13  where product in ('milk', 'meat')
 14  group by deliveryno
 15  having count(*) = 2;

DELIVERYNO
----------
         1
         3

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, that is perfect. It works on the data set that I am currently working on.

Comment: Thank you for the help!!